# Hyperlink Underline

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following Twitter Bootstrap "Stacked Pills" list, mimicking the example shown at http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#navs

```
<div class="navbar-inner">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
        <li class="nav-header">noun</li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">a soft partly suppressed laugh</a></li>
        <li class="nav-header">verb</li>
        <li><a href="#">laugh quietly or with restraint</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">this isn't really a definition; it's just an example of a long one</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

When it renders (in Google Chrome) I get this:

[image: Incorrect]

Compare this to the example shown on the Twitter Bootstrap website:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Messages</a></li>
</ul>
```

[image: Correct]

Why do the `<a>` links have underlines in my version but not on the Twitter Bootstrap example? I'm sure it's 'something obvious' but I'm new to web UI development. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is probably CSS that eliminates the underline for the underline in `<a>` tags.  You can do that by adding

```
a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

to your CSS.  This will remove underlines for all links.  To specify for a specific id or class, just specify your id or class before `a{` as you normally would.

Answer (score 2):

Add `.nav a { text-decoration:none}` to your stylesheet.